# Vagrant package - no files were included in resulting box

Tags: vagrant

I'm trying to export my Vagrant machine. I ran `vagrant package mymachine` on computer A and then copied the resulting package.box file to computer B. Then ran `vagrant box add package.box --name mymachine` (on computer B). Everything seemed to work fine. Then I ran `vagrant up mymachine` (using the Vagrantfile I copied from  computer A) and `vagrant ssh mymachine` and found out none of the files in the original machine were present on the new one. Any ideas as to what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you copied the Vagrantfile from the Computer A, its likely it does not reference your new box. Edit the Vagrantfile on Computer B and change this part

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "mymachine"
  ...
end
```

when you'll boot the instance from this VM (you might need to destroy the current VM and recreate it) it will create a new VM from the newmachine VM

Comment: I don't understand. Should I edit `config.vm.box` to point to the exported file?

Comment: not the exported file but the name of the new box - run `vagrant box list` after you have imported your box and use this same name in the `config.vm.box` in the Vagrantfile